# cross domain relation

Tags: dns, cross-domain

suppose I have www.usa.com as main site. I will create www.utah.com..www.indiana.com...etc on same dedicated server with same hosting. After creating those usa-state sites I will register users from www.usa.com and place them under different states and will give them their own site like www.utah.com/andy . Here user Andy was registered from www.usa.com but placed under www.utah.com. If I search user Andy from www.utah.com or www.usa.com i can get his details but i cant get his details from www.indiana.com.

how i can achieve the above like registered from one site but placed in another site? do u recommend one database-multiple domain concept? how should i approach to built this type of application? pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description it sounds more like your application (as a single app) would be logically organized like this:

usa.com
usa.com/utah
usa.com/utah/andy
usa.com/indiana
...

You could use separate domains for the states through some URL rewriting to achieve what you want.  Your application would handle the search logic.

-OR-

The alternative is to setup each site as it's own application.  The usa site would just be configured to search each of the state sites (via a query string maybe) and aggregate the results.

I know there are other ways to setup what you are looking for but I think these are probably the two major alternatives.

Comment: thanks. I would like to go for this "You could use separate domains for the states through some URL rewriting to achieve what you want. Your application would handle the search logic" .Because I think its dynamic and more logical rather than creating state wise sites. And I think it will save my cost also.

Can you please give me some link where I can find the information about the type of URL rewriting I have to do?